# Using view models to get data back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, viewmodel

Assume we have update form.

This form requires two actions. One of them for GET request to show data and second for POST request to save changes.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    var viewModel = GetViewModel(id);
    viewModel.Dictionaries = GetUpdateDictionaries(id);
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if(Model.IsValid)
    { 
        Save(viewModel);
        return RedirectToHome();
    }
    viewModel.Dictionaries = GetUpdateDictionaries(id);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

It is a classical approach. We pass to POST update the same view model. But with this view model we pass many unnecessary data. For example dictionaries. Someone tells that it is a bad practice and suggest two alternative ways:

1) Use view model only for form data and pass dictionaries and other stuuf through ViewBug
2) Create special class only for necessary form data and use it in post update action.

Are there standart approach?

Comment: The dictionaries will only get rendered or posted back if you create form fields or Html.EditorFor(...) tags for them. So I think the suggestion it is bad practise is wrong and your code is fine as is.

Comment: Make Special classes for necessary form data which u want to post...

Comment: @Kartikeya Khosla yes it is one of the options. But i want to understand what is better and why. What is industrial practice.

Comment: @Chris F Carroll But people say we don't need to have excess data which we don't use. And they have a point. But i don't like suggested solution.

Comment: Is viewModel.Dictionaries used in your view? If so, it isn't excess.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking that viewModel.Dictionaries will all get sent to the client browser and then get posted back to the server? It won't. Only things that you render in markup e.g. with Html.TextBoxFor() get sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionaries are not part of the Model then the alternatives which MVC provide for passing information to the View is:

```
ViewData["MyDictionaries"]= GetUpdateDictionaries(id);
```

or

```
TempData["MyDictionaries"]= GetUpdateDictionaries(id);
```

or for .Net 4:

```
ViewBag.MyDictionaries= GetUpdateDictionaries(id);
```

Is your concern that viewModel.Dictionaries will all get sent to the client browser and then get posted back to the server? It won't. Only things that you render in markup e.g. with Html.TextBoxFor() get sent to the browser. So your current code is okay from that point of view.

The real objection to your dictionaries is, if the dictionaries are not a part of the thing your Model is a model of. The point of OO is that your models are models of *something*; so should only have properties corresponding to the *something* that it models.

If your models are not models of something, but only ViewModels, then putting the dictionaries on them in fine. But in that case, `Save(model)` would not be fine.